In RaspBerry5 Wifi is not reconnecting to saved network often
I have created an application in RPI5 and the application has a wifi page where i can on and off the wifi so when i toggle that button sudo nmcli radio wifi ${args ? "on" : "off"} will be executed based on toggle value. Everytime the wifi enables correctly but it is not auto reconnecting to the saved networks sometimes. 60% of the time wifi is not trying to reconnect.
Can anyone tell about any root cause or solution to this

It is far from clear WHAT you did or WHY you are attempting to achieve.

You can try to set the autoconnect property to yes for your saved network:  sudo nmcli connection modify <Your_SSID> connection.autoconnect yes

Already the autoconnect property is set yes
It works sometimes properly but most times not
